# Scheduling Commands and Tasks Laravel

Tags: laravel

I was wondering if this would be a way to go to create a command for a task, or at least if t would work?
Thanks in advance!

```
$schedule->command('someCommand')
         ->call('Path\To\MyController@method'{ 
          })
         ->dailyAt('00:00');
```

Comment: if my answer was helpful, please choose it as best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to create your own custom commands. Read this tutorial to create your own `artisan` command:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan

Comment: What do I put in the command file, the whole logic of my controller method or I just call my method from the command file?

Comment: If you already have logic in your controller which you use, then just call it from a command class.

Comment: Or maybe it would be even better to put all the logic from the controller to a third class, and call it from both command and controller when you need it. (because both command and controller are just an interface to interact with the app).

Comment: So, if I would call my method from the command class, would that then look like this?  First list path to my controller where I list the classes that I use and then in:   public function handle()
                       {
                         $this->mymethod();
                        }

Comment: What if I wanted to make a method call to execute only at a certain time. How would I do that?